# Custom database.com objects ( ..."__c") and databasedotcom-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, databasedotcom-gem

We are trying to move an existing RoR app to database.com & heroku using the databasedotcom and databasedotcom-rails gems. However, on database.com the API name of Custom Objects MUST end with "__c" and we are finding this is breaking the existing code, especially code using the simple_forms gem.  Many areas assume the name of the model is the same as the classname of the objects and we were unsuccessfull changing the model name to have the ending "__c". 
Any suggestions?